# C#: Assembly DLL not visible to Visual Studio when Debugging using Attach Process

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, .net-assembly, windows-media-center

I am working on a Plugin for Windows Media Center using Visual Studio 2010 Professional, C#, the Windows Media Center SDK 6.0 and NET Framework 2.0.

I am able to create an installer for the app (using WiX Installer), which inserts the app into WMC just fine.

However, I wish to debug the app by using the 'Attach The Process' feature in VS, showing my immediate changes by opening up the plugin within WMC (really cool feature). When I click Start Debugging, the app is opened. However, my changes are not present and I am shown the following error in VS:

> "The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or
>   without debug information:
>
> C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UltraPlaylists\1.0.0.0__d56c5e467dd76093\MyProject.dll
>
> To debug this module, change its project buld configuration to Debug
>   mode. To suppress this message, disable the 'Warn if no user code on
>   launch' debugger option."

One thing I noticed when following these instructions ([MSDN Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb189051.aspx)) is that on Step 6, I should "Locate the DLL that represents your application assembly, right-click it, and choose Symbol Settings."

However, I can not see this application assembly in the list of DLLs. I believe this could be the reason I'm receiving the earlier message.

Comment: Missing PDB file? Perhaps you need to compile for DEBUG instead of RELEASE? I believe the PDB file is necessary to debug something: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I do compile for Debug and in my project bin/Debug folder a MyProject.dll and MyProject.pdb files are produced. However they do not show up in VS Modules Window.

Comment: Hmm, could it be you need add the bin/Debug folder to your list of `Symbol file (.pdb) locations` in dialog show in step 6 of the MSDN instructions you mention?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried that and it didn't work.